# Map enum elements

Tags: java, enums

I have this Java enum structure:

```
public enum MOStatus {
    DRAFT, 
    ACTIVE,
    ARCHIVED
}
```

I would like to map the values with a list:

```
private static Predicate moStatusStatusIn(MOStatus... statuses) {
    List<String> status = Arrays.stream(statuses).map(MOStatus::values).collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

But I get error `Static method referenced through receiver` for `MOStatus::values`

What is the proper way to map the values?

Comment: What do you want to get as result? A list of Strings like {"ACTIVE","ARCHIVED"}, when the two MOStatus ACTIVE and ARCHIVED get passed to the method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Arrays.stream(statuses).map(Enum::name).collect(Collectors.toList())
```